# merging 2 sorted files efficiently with pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have on my HDFS 2 datasets with exactly the same structure, both sorted on the same key. I would like to merge them into one big dataset sorted on that key.

Now I know that pig has an efficient merge-join (http://wiki.apache.org/pig/PigMergeJoin) does it also have an efficient merge-sort?

Comment: What do you mean by "have an efficient merge-sort"? Are you familiar with MapReduce or are you just using pig?

Comment: Thomas: I am and what I meant is "map-side only job", but I sense from the tone of your comment that I missed something basic :)...

Comment: ah :) No map-side only is never sorted ;)

Comment: Thomas: awww man.. so what your'e saying is that it will take exactly the same time no-matter if the datasets are pre-sorted or not?

Comment: Yep. The datasets will get shuffled before the sort in front of the reduce phase.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a smart loader ([like Zebra](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/zebra_pig.html#Map-Side+Group+and+Merge+Join)) could create the correct splits from an index for each map and a `COGROUP USING 'merge'` followed by a `GENERATE group` still keep the order?

If not a new `UNION USING 'merge'` would be perfect in this case!

Answer (score 0):

the output of a merge-join will be a single sorted list. so you don't need a separate sort.